# How can I configure my WiFi interface depending on the selected network?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, wpa-supplicant

I am running an (Arch) linux system with a WiFi card. Depending on the wireless network I am connected to (aka the SSID connected by wpa_supplicant), I eventually want to add configurations.

For example: If I am at home, I have a dedicated DNS server, that provides different IPs than when I am not at home. That way, I can reach certain machines from public internet through the ISP but locally I can just use the faster local network without routing packages once through the ISP. Long story short: I want to set DNS settings depending on the location/SSID I am connected to. Ideally, this should be possible for all network individually.

Normally, I would use systemd-resolvd but if there are better options, feel free to point me there.

Thanks